# Function that returns multiple types

Tags: generics, rust

fn index is called in main like so: `let result = api.index("data>id");`

I want to check if `obj` is a (Enum)`ObjectType::Number` if it is then I want to return as an `i32`.

I don't know if I should be using `T` or a different type.

Full error message: [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SZrH.png)

```
pub fn index<T>(&self, index: &str) -> T {
    let go = index.split('>').collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    let mut current: Node = self.nodes[0].clone();

    for select in go {
        current = self.search_node(&current, select);
    }

    match current {
        Node::ValueNode(val, obj) => {
            match obj {
                ObjectType::Number => {
                    return val.clone() as i32;
                },
                ObjectType::String => {
                    return val.clone();
                },
                ObjectType::Bool => {
                    return val.clone() as bool;
                },
                ObjectType::Null => {
                    return None;
                },
                _ => {
                    return val.clone();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be much simpler to explain what you want, instead of asking help about what you think you need to do to solve you original problem. you are in a https://xyproblem.info/ case. Please [edit] your question and add information, context, the more the better.

Comment: This is not how generics work in Rust. Generic functions with a generic return type are more strict in what they can return, not less. In your example, you must return a `T`  without even knowing what a `T` is. Returning a `i32` because you are sure `T` will be `i32` is not enough: the only things you can assume about `T` are its bounds, and you have none.

Comment: How do you plan to call `index()`? Does the caller know what type will be returned or do they have no idea?

Comment: What does the caller do with `result` after `let result = api.index("data>id");`? I want to pull the thread on this to have you think about how the calling code will look like, because that will inform how `index` is written. Do you imagine the caller somehow knowing and hardcoding that `result` is an `i32`? Or do you expect the caller to do some sort of dynamic type check with their own `match` block or some such thing?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I appreciate all of your help!

I decided to just return `ObjectType` and have an `as_int`(etc) function.

```
pub fn index(&self, index: &str) -> ObjectType {
    let go = index.split('>').collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    let mut current: Node = self.nodes[0].clone();

    for select in go {
        current = self.search_node(&current, select);
    }

    match current {
        Node::ValueNode(val, obj) => {
            return obj;
        }
        _ => {
            return ObjectType::Null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I ultimately decided to do.

Once again thanks so much.